# Is there a dm script command to control the GIF cinema mode

Tags: dm-script

I have been making digital micrograph scripts to take some sequential frame acquisitions on a JEOL ARM200F. For some experiments, I need a faster readout speed than the usual CCD acquisition mode can do.
The GIF Quantum camera is able to do a "cinema" mode in which half the pixels are used as memory storage such that the camera can be exposed and read out simultaneously. This is utilized for EELS acquisitions.

Does anybody know if there is a DM scripting command to activate (acquire images in) the cinema mode?

My current script sets the number of frames to acquire, the acquisition time per frame, and binning. However the readout time between each frame is too slow. Setting the camera to cinema mode before running the script still only acquires full frame images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no simple command for this. The advanced camera modes are not available as simple commands, and they are generally not part of the supported DM-script interface.

Usually, these modes can only be accessed via the object-oriented camera-script interface (*CM_* commands) used by Gatan service and R&D. This script interface is, at least until now, *not* end-user supported.
It definitely falls into the category of 'advanced' scripting, so you will need to know how to handle object-oriented script coding style.

---

With the above said, the following might help you, if you already know how to use the CM_ commands in general:

In the extended (not enduser - supported) script interface, the way to achieve *cinema mode* is to modify the acquisition parameter set. One needs to set the *readMode* parameter.
The following code snipped shows this:

```
object camera = cm_GetCurrentCamera()
number read_mode = camera.cm_GetReadModeForNamedAcquisitionStyle("Cinema")

number create_if_not_exist = 1;
object acq_params = camera.CM_GetCameraAcquisitionParameterSet("Imaging", "Acquire", "Record", create_if_not_exist)
cm_SetReadMode(acq_params, read_mode)

cm_Validate_AcquisitionParameters(camera, acq_params);
image img := cm_AcquireImage(camera, acq_params)
img.ShowImage()
```

Note, that not all cameras support the *Cinema* readmode. The second line command will throw an error message in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have used some scripts that use the CM_commands so have some ideas and references on how to write them. I will try to contact some people about the specific commands I am interested in.

Comment: @msch Ok, that's good to know. I've edited my answer above after a bit of research. This should hopefully help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code update. I was able to add some of these commands into my code and achieve the frame transfer (cinema mode) movie acquisition. Unfortunately the acquisitions are still not as fast as I need them but I'm glad that I was able to test it.

Comment: @msch That's perfect. If the answer is solved for you, could you please "accept" the answer to mark this question closed? (Checkbox at the up/down-vote buttons on the top left of the answer.)

Comment: @msch You are likely running into a different issues here: If you are doing single-frame acquisitions, you're having an overhead of some hundredths of a second. This is not the same as "live view". Here, you need to set up a continuous acquisition with an image-source and listener. Also CM_ API stuff.. and a bit different to handle than single-frame (synchronous) script calls.

Comment: I have been acquiring stacks with `acq_params.CM_SetDoAcquireStack(true)` along with `CM_SetFrameExposure` and `CM_SetExposure`. I'm not sure if this is different from "live view" acquisition.

Comment: @msch That is different. I was referring to the method where one sets up an image-source object with `CM_AcquisitionImageSource` and uses the `IMGSRC_` commands to grab data continuously.